# Get xlim and ylim for AxesSubplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Consider

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot
figure, axes = pyplot.subplots(1, 2)
```

Now there are ways to `set` the `xlim` and `ylim` like

```py
axes[0].set_xlim([0, 5])
axes[0].set_ylim([0, 5])

axes[1].set_xlim([0, 5])
axes[1].set_ylim([0, 5])
```

but there is no getter for the same thing. I have created a plot in one of the axes and after creating it, I need to know the `xlim` and `ylim` but apparently, there is no method.

```
plt.xlim()
plt.ylim()
```

don't give the required results.

Comment: `x=axes[1].get_xlim()` etc. See [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xlim.html)

Comment: This worked as expected. Thanks

Comment: In matplotlib, when you find a `.set_ABCXYZ()` function, you can safely assume that the inverse `.get_ABCXYZ()` function also exists, and vice versa.